# HTML TextArea to PHP Array variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, ajax

I have a side-projects, I was a little confused about HTML Forms, and it was TextArea to make it array when in PHP Environment (that also making me more confused)

I have file func.php

```
# define file array
$user_files = isset($_POST['url'])?$_POST['url']:"";

//I dont check for empty() incase your app allows a 0 as ID.
if (strlen($user_files)==url) {
  echo 'Error';
  exit;
}

$files = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $user_files));

# create new zip object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
```

also index.html

```
<form class="download_file" action="func.php" method="post">
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" align="center">
    <textarea id="url" ng-model="loremIpsum" ng-keyup="autoExpand($event)" placeholder="Insert URL (1 URL per Lines)">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div><br>
<button type="submit" name="button">
<div class="button">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tick">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </button>
```

Comment: In `if (strlen($user_files)==url) {`, `url` is a valid constant ?

Comment: your textarea has no name attribute.

Comment: well, someone (my friend of course) tell me if that is ID is used from HTML form, but I think it's not.

Comment: did I really must also have name attribute?

Comment: @Scuzzy has right : `$_POST['url']` gets value of element with `name="url"` (inside a form with `method="post"`).

Comment: If you dont put the name attribute, the textarea will not be sent.